# Text on the left with line on the right in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I create the following in HTML and CSS?

Some Text ---------------------------------------------------------

The line should be solid, no dotted

Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? What is your markup? Should the line occupy all of the remaining space? There's nowhere near enough information to make this question answerable.

Comment: please follow the guide of stack overflow "how to write a good question". 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using flexbox like this:

```css
.text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
 
.text::after {
  content: "";
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          -ms-flex: 1;
              flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
   -ms-grid-row-align: center;
           align-self: center;

  margin-left: 8px; /*space before line*/
  height: 2px;      /*line thickness*/
  background: #333; /*line color*/
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Some Text</div>
```

Comment: I'm not here trying to judge your answer, but I think that is not a good idea to use some CSS features with low browser supports such as "flex"  and pseudo, while the problem can be solved with another CSS techniques that have better browsers supports.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I agree with you mostly, but to be fair, as you pointed out, there isn't a lot of information to go on in the question. The only point I'd disagree with is about support. Neither flexbox nor pseudo elements can be said to have "low" support in 2017 _(from caniuse.com: [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), [pseudo elements](http://caniuse.com/#search=pseudo-elements))_. I've been using both in production since early last year and only ever needed a fallback for IE11. That being said, although my answer works for almost all browsers, I still agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with the following code snippet:

```
<style>
    .inline-hr {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
Some text <hr class="inline-hr"/>
```

Then you can make the line as wide as you want by adjusting the width in style.